# Return all Data excluding current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I wish to retrieve all data, though I wish to exclude the current month.

The where statement that I'm using is

```
and MONTH(MOPEFD) <= MONTH(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())))
```

When I run it in Feb, I only get data for Jan 2020, Jan 2019, Jan 2018, Jan 2017.

I wish to get data for Jan 2020, Dec 2019, Nov 2018...... to the start.

Next month I will wish to get Feb 2020, Jan 2020..... to the start.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You're only comparing months. =

Answer (score 1):

You can use [handy date function `eomonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) (which was introduced in SQL Server 2012):

```
where mopefd < dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -1))
```

`eomonth(getdate(), -1)` gives you the last day of last month. You can just add one day to that, and use it as an (non-inclusive) upper limit for the search.

Side note: as commented by HABO, if `mopefd` has no time part, the expression can be simplified:

```
where mopefd <= eomonth(getdate(), -1)
```

Comment: If `MOPEFD` is a `Date` then `MOPEFD <= EoMonth( GetDate(), -1 )` will suffice. If the data type includes a time then it needs to be compared to the start of the following day so that all of the times on the last day of the month are included.

Comment: @HABO: yes that's a good point, I added it in my answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, I would recommend:

```
where mopefd < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

If you don't care about index usage or partition pruning, you can also use:

```
where datediff(month, mopefd, getdate()) >= 1
```